# SSIS package email with attachments

Tags: ssis, varbinary

I'm building an SSIS package that selects a recordset of email data, loops through them, and then emails them out through send mail tasks.  I have a table for emails, a table for addresses, and a table for attachments.  Right now my SSIS package loops through the emails table and for each record populates the variables for body and subject.

From there I have a foreach loop that loops through the address table and populates the variables for the to and CC properties of the send mail task.

From there I have a foreach loop that loops through the attachments table similarly to the process for the address table.  The problem is that the attachment data is stored as varbinary and I cannot figure out how to import it into SSIS.  There's no varbinary type and also the FileAttachments property in SSIS is looking for a file path.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Variable Data Type that can accept VARBINARY data.